# Is it possible to get all values for a Redis set in one operation?

Tags: redis

Say I add two keys:

```
SET husband Bob
SET wife Alice
```

Then add these to a set:

```
SADD family husband wife
```

I can get the *keys* of this set with `SMEMBERS family`, which will return:

```
1) "wife"
2) "husband"
```

What I really want is the *values*:

```
1) "Alice"
2) "Bob"
```

Is this possible, in one operation?  Essentially, I want to pipeline `SMEMBERS` with `MGET`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`SMEMBERS`](http://redis.io/commands/smembers), but if the Set is big enough your database will take time to return all the members, during which it will be blocked. In such cases the use of [`SSCAN`](http://redis.io/commands/sscan) is recommended.

EDIT: missed the question itself :) use `SORT family BY nosort GET *`

Comment: `SMEMBERS` returns the _keys_.  I want the _values_.

Comment: Could you share a reference please on how `SORT family BY nosort GET *` works, complexity etc?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to understand is Redis doesn't allow you to put a set in a set - no nested data structures. Likewise they are no vets and values in a set - only members which are strings in your case. This is why you can't "get the values".

It really sounds like the structure you are wanting is not a set but a hash. Using a hash will allow you do do exactly what you ask for.

`hset family husband bob`
`hset family wife alice`

And then to get what you call the values use `hvals family`.

This is the proper way to do it as it uses the right data structure, matches  your terminology to the structure, and provides exaxtly what you want led without the performance penalties of sort. Further it allows you to use the various hash commands to select or update specific members of the family.

You could also use `hgetall` to use the mapping. That way your code knows Alice is the wife rather than the daughter.

Overall hashes are certainly the way to go here for virtually every reason.